# inode array placement on spinning disk

Tags: io, disk, inode

"Assume a spinning disk. Where on that disk would you place the inode array?"

This is one of the questions one my homework assignment, and I can't seem to find material relating inode arrays & spinning disks. Could someone point me in the right direction/help explain this? Thanks.

Comment: This is a common sense question, and you don't need material to come up with a solution. Picture a CD rotating in space. If you needed to find something as fast as possible, which part of that disk would be the quickest to make a full rotation to help you get there faster? If you can't visualize it, trace the outer and inner edges of the CD on a piece of paper, and use your finger to trace those edges as quickly as possible. Where would you put the inode array?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question.